# Rails bootstrap modal login using Monban authentication issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, bootstrap-modal

I'm using the gem Monban for user authentication am trying to implement modal usage for users to login/signup/edit etc. I am able to sign up a user through bootstrap modal use no problem at all using `form_for User.new` etc, however I can't do the same to log a user in. I've tried `form_for Session.new` but it errors and says `uninitialized constant` on homepage load, before even seeing the modal. I've tried `form_for new_session_path`, and i see the modal this time but get the error message `No route matches [POST] "/"`. I've also tried using `form_tag` and other combinations but still no luck. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great! Please see my code below:

### view/modals/_signin.html.erb

```
<div id="signin-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome Back!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <%= form_for Session.new do |f| %>
            <div>
              <span class="model-label"><%= f.label :username %></span>
              <p><%= f.text_field :username, placeholder: "Username..", required: true, class: "modal-input" %><p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="model-label"><%= f.label :password %></span>
              <p><%= f.password_field :password, require: true, placeholder: "Password..", class: "modal-input" %></p>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= f.submit "Sign In", class: "btn btn-info" %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

### sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:new, :create], raise: false

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = authenticate_session(session_params)

    if sign_in(user)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def session_params
    params.require(:session).permit(:username, :password)
  end
end
```

### config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :chats, only: [:show, :update, :index] do
    resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
  end
  resources :comments, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  resources :posts, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  resources :locations, only: [:edit, :update]
  resources :profiles, only: [:show, :edit, :update] do
    resources :chats, only: [:new, :create]
    resources :locations, only: [:new, :create], module: :profiles
    resources :posts, only: [:new, :create]
  end
  resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :index, :update] do
      post 'follow', to: 'following_relationships#create'
    delete 'follow', to: 'following_relationships#destroy'
      post 'tutor',  to: 'tutoring_relationships#create'
    delete 'tutor',  to: 'tutoring_relationships#destroy'
  end
  root 'home#index'
end
```

*which give me the following routes*

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
       chat_comments POST   /chats/:chat_id/comments(.:format)            comments#create
    new_chat_comment GET    /chats/:chat_id/comments/new(.:format)        comments#new
               chats GET    /chats(.:format)                              chats#index
                chat GET    /chats/:id(.:format)                          chats#show
                     PATCH  /chats/:id(.:format)                          chats#update
                     PUT    /chats/:id(.:format)                          chats#update
        edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)                  comments#edit
             comment PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)                       comments#update
                     PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                       comments#update
                     DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                       comments#destroy
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                     posts#edit
                post PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                          posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                          posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                          posts#destroy
       edit_location GET    /locations/:id/edit(.:format)                 locations#edit
            location PATCH  /locations/:id(.:format)                      locations#update
                     PUT    /locations/:id(.:format)                      locations#update
       profile_chats POST   /profiles/:profile_id/chats(.:format)         chats#create
    new_profile_chat GET    /profiles/:profile_id/chats/new(.:format)     chats#new
   profile_locations POST   /profiles/:profile_id/locations(.:format)     profiles/locations#create
new_profile_location GET    /profiles/:profile_id/locations/new(.:format) profiles/locations#new
       profile_posts POST   /profiles/:profile_id/posts(.:format)         posts#create
    new_profile_post GET    /profiles/:profile_id/posts/new(.:format)     posts#new
        edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                  profiles#edit
             profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)                       profiles#show
                     PATCH  /profiles/:id(.:format)                       profiles#update
                     PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)                       profiles#update
             session POST   /session(.:format)                            sessions#create
         new_session GET    /session/new(.:format)                        sessions#new
                     DELETE /session(.:format)                            sessions#destroy
         user_follow POST   /users/:user_id/follow(.:format)              following_relationships#create
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/follow(.:format)              following_relationships#destroy
          user_tutor POST   /users/:user_id/tutor(.:format)               tutoring_relationships#create
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/tutor(.:format)               tutoring_relationships#destroy
               users GET    /users(.:format)                              users#index
                     POST   /users(.:format)                              users#create
            new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                          users#new
                user PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                          users#update
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#update
                root GET    /                                             home#index
```

Thanks, and please let me know if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I see following in Rails documentation for [singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) (resource command)

> A long-standing bug prevents form_for from working automatically with
>   singular resources. As a workaround, specify the URL for the form
>   directly, like so:

```
resource :geocoder
form_for @geocoder, url: geocoder_path do |f|
```

So should be something like this in your case:

```
<%= form_for Session.new, url: session_path do |f| %>
```

By the way, new_session_path is not what you want anyway, as new is for the form rendering and not saving (creating) the object.

Comment: @pavel_bulanov thanks for the answer but i still get an error. This time ```uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Session``` I've completely hit a wall and can't work out what to to

Comment: Does it happen on page load or after submitting the form? Maybe give a bit more of stacktrace. When it happens - does create method run? In the meantime, you have `render :new` for login error - do you have corresponding view? It should be under view/sessions

Comment: Also, for this specific error try searching SO, e.g. [this]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588749/uninitialized-constant-actionviewcompiledtemplatescategory) answer - maybe it helps